# Update observable list in ionic page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have just started to learn this ionic/angular. So, I have a ionic page which shows a list of observable items fetched through a service. On clicking any item, a popover is opened by passing item id to it.

This item id is used to fetch and show item details inside the popover. Lastly inside the popover, there is this submit button which updates the item status to 1.

MainPage.html

```
<div *ngFor="let bill of Bills$ | async">
  <ion-label>{{bill.Name}}</ion-label>
  {{bill.Description}}
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-button (click)="openBill(bill.Id)">Draft Bill</ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
</div>
```

MainPage.component.ts

```
  Bills$: Observable<Bill[]>;

  openBill(ev:any){
    console.log("Bill Id: "+ev);
    this.presentPopover(ev);
  }

  async presentPopover(ev: any) {
    const popover = await this.popoverController.create({
      component: DraftbillPage,
      componentProps: {
        "BillId": ev
      },
      cssClass: 'my-custom-class',
      event: ev,
      translucent: true
    });
    return await popover.present();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getBills();
  }

  getBills() {
    this.Bills$ = this.userService.getBills();
  }
```

UserService.ts

```
export class UserService {
  user: User;
  Bills$: Observable<Bill[]>;

  constructor() {   
    this.user = new User();
    this.user.Bills = Bills;   
    this.Bills$ = of(this.user.Bills);
  }

  //Method called through popover update item status from 0 to 1
  DraftBill(Id: number) {
    this.user.Bills.filter(b => b.Id == Id)[0].Status = 1;
  }

  //Method called through main page to fetch list of items with status 0
  getBills(): Observable<Bill[]> {
    return this.Bills$.pipe(
      map(bills => bills.filter(b => b.Status == 0))
    );
  }

  //Method called through popover to item details
  getBill(Id: number): Observable<Bill> {
    return this.Bills$.pipe(
      map(bills => bills.filter(b => b.Id == Id)[0])
    );
  }
}
```

The issue is my list in the main page is not getting updated after changing item status. I want to update my list in main page with only items having status as 0. I am not sure if my approach is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code you do create Observable 'of' **this.user.Bills** initially, but then you modify the source array in this code below and not the array subscribers are getting via your Observable:

```
DraftBill(Id: number) {
    this.user.Bills.filter(b => b.Id == Id)[0].Status = 1;
}
```

Your observable is a stream of the emitted array. So your Observable<Bill[]>is not an array that's being observed by some observer, it's actually a stream of emitted Bill[] array. So you can't update the emitted value as it already has been emitted, but what you want is for your observable to emit another value, an updated array of Bills.

Seems like you need a Subject, an object that is both Observable and Observer (it inherits from both Observer and Observable interfaces). And in your specific case you might need a BehaviorSubject which emits initial value to any subscriber:

```
Bills$: BehaviorSubject<Bill[]> = new BehaviorSubject( here is the original array );
```

Now to modify its value you could:

```
this.Bills$.next( new array with updated values )
```

Now all templates subscribed to this BehaviorSubject will propagate new values.

If you could share the full code that you have at stackblitz, it should be easy to modify what you have.

So your service could be like:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class UserService {

  user: User;
  Bills$: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

  constructor() {   
    this.user = new User();
    this.user.Bills = Bills;   
    this.Bills$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.user.Bills);
  }

  DraftBill(Id: number) { 
      this.user.Bills.filter(b => b.Id == Id)[0].Status = 1; 
      this.Bills$.next(this.user.Bills); 
  }

  getBills(): Observable<Bill[]> {
    return this.Bills$.pipe(
      map(bills => bills.filter(b => b.Status == 0))
    );
  }

  getBill(Id: number): Observable<Bill> {
    return this.Bills$.pipe(
      map(bills => bills.filter(b => b.Id == Id)[0])
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked. But I had to modify DraftBill() method from,
`{ this.Bills$.value.filter(b => b.Id == Id)[0].Status = 1; }`
to
`{ this.user.Bills.filter(b => b.Id == Id)[0].Status = 1;`
`this.Bills$.next(this.user.Bills); }`